# Can I restore software update?

Tags: updates, ota-update, restore

I'm trying to re-install a software update for my Galaxy S6, because I don't think it installed properly. Before the update, my phone was running smoothly, but now it freezes and is very slow.

Answer (score 3):

### Wiping `/data`

If you were upgrading Android versions, the OTA might not have wiped your `/data` partition properly, and this may cause the issues that you describe. You should first try to perform a factory reset to see if that resolves the issue. One way to do this is through **Settings > Backup & reset > Factory data reset**. If you can't access your settings menu, you can perform the reset from recovery with these instructions:

1. Completely power off your phone. Now press and hold the **volume up, home, and power buttons** all at the same time until you see small blue text on the screen. This is your recovery.
2. Use the **volume up/down and power** buttons navigate down to `wipe data/factory reset` > select `Yes -- delete all user data`.
3. Now select `wipe cache partition`.
4. Once that is complete select `reboot system now`. Your phone will now boot up like usual, but it may take up to 10 minutes, so be patient!

***If this doesn't resolve your issue, continue reading to find out how to reinstall the system image:***

### Reinstalling `/system`

You can reinstall an OTA update by downloading the firmware .tar and installing it via Odin. You can find the latest .tar update for your S6 on the [XDA firmware thread for all Galaxy S6 variants](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/general/stock-firmware-official-stock-firmware-t3086387).

1. With your phone unplugged, we're going to enter into `Download Mode`. Power off your phone and press and hold the **volume down, home button, and power button all at the same time**.
2. You should see `Warning` on the screen. Press **volume up** to continue.
3. You will now see `Downloading...`.
4. Plug in your phone via microUSB to your computer. If you have the official Samsung USB cable, use it.
5. [**Download `Odin3_v3.10.6.zip`**](http://downloadandroidfiles.org/file-php/?File=/Tools/Odin3_v3.10.6.zip) and the correct stock firmware using the XDA thread mentioned above.
6. Unzip the stock firmware you downloaded in step 5. The unzipped file should end in "XXXX.md5".
7. Unzip `Odin3_v3.10.6.zip` and run `Odin3 v3.10.6.exe`.
8. You should see a blue box on the left side of Odin that reads something similar to **0:[COM15]**, if you don't then download and install [Samsung USB drivers](http://downloadandroidfiles.org/file-php/?File=/Drivers/Samsung_USB_Driver_for_Moblie_Phones_v1_4_6_0.exe).
9. In Odin click on **AP**, locate and select the md5 file you unzipped in step 6. Odin may show **Not Responding**, but just wait!
10. Click on **Start** and wait until the process is over. This can take up to 15 minutes so be patient! (If you get **FAIL!** check the FAQ sections in the source link below).
11. Once the process is completed you will see **PASS!** and your phone will automatically reboot. Your phone can take up to 10 minutes to fully boot up the first time, be patient!

*Your phone is now restored to stock Samsung firmware, but follow the steps in the first part of the post to reset your `/user` data for best results.*

---

*Adapted from ["How to Unroot/Unbrick Galaxy S6 and S6 Edge!" from AndroidRootz.com](http://www.androidrootz.com/2015/05/how-to-unroot-galaxy-s6-and-s6-edge.html).*